# How to import a library from an nx project into my angular project

Tags: angular, npm, nomachine-nx

I have a components library in an NX project, and I want to include these components in a new Angular project, this Angular project is generated only with the Angular CLI.

I've tried to build and package the library and do an npm install in the angular project, it gets the components references in the IDE, but when i call it in my app it says failed to import all the components with a 404 browser error.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow. What are the components ? How do you include it ? Please consider the fact we can't see your screen and don't know your project. Please edit your question to contain all the information (code) - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)